# Undelete a deleted object

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been tracking down the lost College apprentices, and Rundi was nowhere to be found. Annoyed, I `prid` him and found that he was deleted (the console selector read *''(000d4ffa)**[D]***). Ilas-Tel, another lost apprentice of the College, had also suffered the same fate. What could have caused an innocent corpse to become deleted and is there any way for me to recover it? Could it be caused by him being raised and then turning into an ash pile?

I've disabled all active plugins to make sure it wasn't just a dirty edit somehwere, but he remained deleted.

Comment: In this case it's probably "safe" to use placeatme to spawn a copy. It will add just that much more data to your save if it works, though.

Comment: Does the `enable` console command work on the deleted object? Also, try it with the `moveto player` console command, to check if a body appears near you.

Comment: @galacticninja I've tried all of that, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think a 'deleted' object can be restored (unlike a 'disabled' object).

From https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Console/Archive_4#Undo_Markfordelete.3F:

> There is no way to create a reversal for the markfordelete command that I have found in my research. I have not found a way to reverse this command once it is entered as it creates a permanent flag on the item to never render it or allow scripts to run for/including it, and it does not seem to be a toggle type command that can be turned on or off. The best way to think of the console is that it is the "master script" for the game that you are live editing when you enter a command: that is why all of the warnings on using the console for anything. This is no help to you, I know: I hope it is a warning to others though

A [thread in the Skyrim Steam forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20170603000302/http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2831563) seems to suggest the same thing. In the same thread, though, [a user suggested to use the `resetinterior` console command](https://web.archive.org/web/20170603000304/http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=31892207&postcount=3) (resets an entire cell) while outside the cell, to try the restore the deleted object in the cell. I'm not sure if this will have negative effects (although I assume it will).

Answer (score 2):

What, I think, is missing from the existing answer is an explanation for the missing Rundi.  This/he is part of the quest:  The Missing Apprentices.

This quest.... does not exist.  It is one of several items of cut content from Skyrim.

However, several mods are available which restore this content, the best known is [The Cutting Room Floor](https://tes-mods.fandom.com/wiki/Cutting_Room_Floor) by [Arthmoor](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/users/684492).

This mod is available, of course, on [Nexus for Skyrim](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/47327), on [Nexus for SSE](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/276), but is also available for the [XBox One](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/2955575).

The Cutting Room Floor is, sadly, not available for the PS4, however there is another mod available for the PS4 that restores this content which is called [Skyrim Restored](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3508920) by [Salvadorc17](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim?author_username=salvadorc17).

Comment: The cut quest aside, I believe Rindi's corpse is supposed to appear (and not be 'deleted') in the unmodded game. https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Rundi "Rundi is a dead Nord found near an altar at an unmarked location east-southeast of Winterhold."

Comment: @galacticninja What I stated above was factual... what I didn't say was that in my opinion there's something funny about Rundi because that corpse has sometimes been there and sometimes not in my play-throughs.  I only play on console (XBox360/XBox One) so I can't determine what's going on.  I'm hopeful that the mods above also "stabilize" his corpse so that it's consistently findable.